# Implicit equation - $G(x,y)=0$

Tags: numerical-methods, functional-equations

I'm confused about some points in  implicit equation ...

From my recitation class   -

> $G(x,y)=0$ provides  - $y=f(x)$ .
>
> And $f'(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$
>
> and about $G'(x,y)=0$ we use  -
>
> [image]

How would be look $f'(x)$ in case of the follow  implicit equation ? -

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have usually seen this called an [implicit function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function).  You are not guaranteed the ability to transform it into the form $y=f(x)$, but you can do [implicit differentiation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_differentiation#Implicit_differentiation)  From $3x^7+2y^5-x^3+y^3-3=0$ you take a derivative with respect to $x$ to get $21x^6+10y^4y'-3x^2+3y^2y'=0, y'=-\frac{21x^6-3x^2}{10y^4+3y^2}$

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$G(x,y)=3x^7+2y^5-x^3+y^3-3=0 $$

so

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}=21x^6-3x^2 $$

$$\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=10y^4+3y^2 $$

therefore

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}}=-\frac{21x^6-3x^2}{10y^4+3y^2} $$